How to calculate total_time of facebook rate limit?
When using instagram graph api of meta, rate limit is the number of API calls an app or user can make within a given time period. Calls within one hour = 200 * Number of Users. But when the number  of user be increased, will total_time (A whole number expressing the percentage of total time allotted for query processing.) be increased too?
Will total_time be increased too?
